# Получить URL на twig

Tags: twig

Использую OpenCart с шаблонизатором Twig. Проблема заключается в том, что не могу получить URL страницы, на котором нахожусь. Функции как path, url, dump просто не работают, выдают ошибку.

Как можно получить URL/Абсолютный URL на twig?

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать так:

```
{% set currentPath = path(app.request.attributes.get('_route'),
                       app.request.attributes.get('_route_params')) %}
```

В это коде мы прочли текущий URL в переменную `currentPath`.  Переменная `app` - это глобальная переменная представлений. В ней есть множество других параметров, которые могут быть полезны. К примеру информация о сессии и токенах безопасности (если таковые имеются).

Ссылка на источник: [get current url in twig template?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9378741/5275890)

И еще для примера. Получение текущего URL:

```
{{ app.request.uri }}
```

и получение пути ([ссылка на источник](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20329384/5275890)):

```
{{ app.request.pathinfo }}
```